# Jekyll post.content with template

Tags: jekyll

I have posts that use a template. I want to display them all on one page like so...

```
{% for post in site.categories.slides %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

This only displays the content of the posts but not rendered within their templates. How do I get the full content of the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to use includes instead of templates...

```
{% for post in site.categories.slides %}
  {% include slide.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This assumes slide.html is only a partial template and not a full template for your whole page ;) Yust as clarification for future readers.